# Azure Service Bus and Messaging Sessions

Tags: azure, azure-queues, azureservicebus

I've been looking into Azure Service Bus Queues (**NOT** Azure Storage Queues). All of the details that I have read indicate that it supports [FIFO semantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx), but only in the context of a "Messaging Session". The problem is that I can't seem to find any information on what exactly this is in the context of Azure. Is this a WCF construct, or something that is particular to Azure Service Bus? I assume that it does not relate to local transactions, but I am not 100% sure.

Any pointers would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specifically it refers to [MessageSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagesession.aspx), and it's the [AcceptMessageSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh293162) method that holds the key by returning messages only for a given session id, which could be a sequence implying some ordering.  The [Brokered Messaging: Session Messages](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-Session-41c43fb4) sample should help clarify, and the [Best Practices](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/) document is another great reference.

Comment: Jim - Thanks for the answer. If I understand, the session id can be used to order messages, but there is nothing in the framework to provide those session ids. Meaning that you have to generate the sequence numbers to use for the session ids for FIFO. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, that's my read as well... I was hoping to find a specific example of FIFO usage, but the sample I mentioned was the closest.

Comment: Thanks Jim. If I put one together that is worth posting, I will add it here.

Comment: Interesting question and answer i am asking the same thing... did you find or create an example for FIFO?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn520246.aspx)

> **SessionId:** If a message has the
>   `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage.SessionId` property set, then Service Bus
>   uses the `SessionId` property as the partition key. This way, all messages that belong to 
>   the same session are handled by the same message broker. This enables Service Bus to
>   guarantee message ordering as well as the consistency of session states.

For a coding sample employing `SessionId` and `AcceptSessionReceiver` [see.](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-Session-41c43fb4)